Does nowhere vanishing $n$-form admits an ordered basis ( in each tangent spaces ) that has a positive value when evaluated to the form?
Simple question : Let $\omega$ be a $C^{\infty}$ nowhere-vanishing $n$-form on $M$ ( a manifold of dimension $n$ ). Then at each point $p \in M$, there exists ordered basis $(X_{1,p} , \dots , X_{n,p})$ for $T_p M$ such that $\omega_p(X_{1,p} , \dots X_{n,p}) > 0$?
This argument appears in the proof of the Loring Tu, An Introduction to Manifolds, Theorem 21.5 :

Theorem 21.5. A manifold $M$ of dimension $n$ is orientable if and only if there exists a $C^{\infty}$ nowhere-vanishing $n$-form on $M$.

Can anyone help?

Of course. Pick any basis; the evaluation will be non-zero since the form is nowhere vanishing. If the result is negative, simply replace the first vector with its negative. Similarly you can even find smooth local vector fields whose evaluation gives a function which is positive in a neighborhood of the given point $p$.

Thanks.  You mean, there exists at least one basis ( in each tangent space ) such that the evaluation is non-zero? Can we prove that by the way of contradiction? Uhm..what is the definiiton of 'nowhere-vanishing'? $\omega_ p \neq 0 $ for each $p\in M$ ?

Or the evaluation is nonzero for any basis?

For the second part, yes that’s the definition. For the first part fix a point $p$; then we’re working on the tangent space $T_pM$. So this is now reduced to a linear algebra problem; show that if $\dim V=n$ and $\omega$ is an $n$-multilinear alternating map from $V^n\to \Bbb{R}$, then it is the zero map if and only if there exists a basis such that the evaluation is $0$, if and only if for every basis the evaluation is $0$. There are many ways of phrasing the proof here, and I’ll let you figure out the details.

O.K.  Thank you for kind explanation and teaching :)

P.s. If you have the Loring Tu's book, then to prove the statement you suggest as a linear algebra problem, we may use the Lemma 21.1 in his book ; Let $u_1, \dots , u_n$ and $v_1 , \dots , v_n$ be vectors in a vector space $V$.  Suppose $$u_j= \Sigma_{i=1}^n v_i a^i_j ,  \ j=1,\dots , n ,$$ for a matrix $A:= [a^i_j]$ of real numbers. If $\beta$ is an $n$-covector on $V$, then $$\beta(u_1, \dots, u_n) = (\det A)\beta(v_1, \dots, v_n).$$ Anyway, thanks.

In your first comment, for me, it seems interesting that we can choose such local vector fields ( whose evaluation gives a function which is positive in a neighborhood of the given point $p$ ) 'smoothly' ! Perhaps can you inform me where can I find associated reference?

Do it yourself; it’s not that hard. You can even take coordinate vector fields. The sign will remain constant on (_a type of open set) due to a very famous theorem.

O.K. ! I will try to it. Thanks.
